# BFS using adjacency lists in STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, stl

I am trying to write a program for implementing BFS in C++ using STL. I am representing the adjacency list using nested vector where each cell in vector contains a list of nodes connected to a particular vertex.

```
while(myQ.size()!=0)
{
    int j=myQ.front();
    myQ.pop();
    int len=((sizeof(adjList[j]))/(sizeof(*adjList[j])));
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if (arr[adjList[j][i]]==0)
        {
            myQ.push(adjList[j][i]);
            arr[adjList[j][i]]=1;
            dist(v)=dist(w)+1;
        }
    }

}
```

myQ is the queue i am using to keep the nodes along whose edges i will be exploring the graph. In the notation adjList[j] represents the vector pointing to the list and adjList[j][i] represents a particular node in that list. I am storing whether i have explored a particular node by inputting 1 in the array arr. Also dist(v)=dist(w)+1 is not a part of the code but i want to know how i can write it in the correct syntax where my v is the new vertex and w is the old one which discovers v i.e w=myQ.front().

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, then you want a data structure to store the distances of the graph nodes.

This can be easily done using map.

Use this:

```
typedef std::map <GraphNode*, int> NodeDist;
NodeDist node_dist;
```

Replace dist(v)=dist(w)+1; with:

```
NodeDist::iterator fi = node_dist.find (w);
if (fi == node_dist.end())
{
    // Assuming 0 distance of node w.
    node_dist[v] = 1;
}
else
{
    int w_dist = (*fi).second;
    node_dist[v] = w_dist + 1;
}
```

Please let me if I have misunderstood your problem or the given solution does not work for you. We can work on that.